# Ubnutu : install lombok in Eclipse IDE show error "can't write directory" even using sudo

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, lombok

I am facing problem to install Lombok on Eclipse, it shows an Error message attached screenshot.

I also tried with root (with sudo) user or with command sudo java -jar lombok.jar . I am using ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  Kindly help, how I install lombok?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this is, you've installed eclipse via snap. Snap is immutable directory, so you cannot add/update code in it.

There are two options to achieve your goal :

Opt 1 -> Create your own eclipse.ini file that runs with lombok. [Here is a good description.](https://www.xceno.io/posts/2019-05-15-install-lombok-to-eclipse-snap)

Opt 2 -> Uninstall eclipse from snap, install it via eclipse web page, than you can surely add your lombok plugin with installer.

Comment: There is no need to edit .desktop files anymore. You can now override the eclipse.ini file (https://github.com/snapcrafters/eclipse/pull/41)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the cause is, but I might have an alternative: Use the Eclipse plug-in.

See the [Eclipse setup page](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse), and follow the instructions under "Via eclipse plugin installer".

Disclaimer: I am a lombok developer.